# List of struct's field names in Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, schema

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- student_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- major: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hounour_roll: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- school_name: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I get a list of columns under "student_info" only? I.e. `["firstname","lastname","major","honour_roll"]`

Comment: `sdf.select('student_info.*').columns` will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the following return the list of struct's field names. The `.columns` approach looks cleanest.

```py
df.select("student_info.*").columns
```

```py
df.schema["student_info"].dataType.names
```

```py
df.schema["student_info"].dataType.fieldNames()
```

```py
df.select("student_info.*").schema.names
```

```py
df.select("student_info.*").schema.fieldNames()
```